# Twig variables as references

Tags: php, symfony, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to change a Twig variable via a php reference but I can't achieve that. I looked around and nor with Twig functions nor with Twig filters I could do what I want. Any idea how to do that?

```
{% set hiding_options_classes = "default" %}
{{ hiding_options_func(content.field_hiding_options, hiding_options_classes) }}
{{ hiding_options_classes }}
```

In my Twig extension file:

```
public function hiding_options_func($hiding_options, &$hiding_options_classes) {
    $hiding_options_classes = "coucou";
}
```

Comment: You might be better of by simply returning the classes you want from `hiding_options_func`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to pass the context by reference if you wanted to change variables inside your extension e.g.

```
class Project_Twig_Extension extends \Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension {

    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new \Twig\TwigFunction('set', [$this, 'setValue'], ['needs_context' => true, ]),
        ];
    }

    public function setValue(&$context, $key, $value) {
        if (isset($context['_parent'])) $context['_parent'][$key] = $value;
        $context[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
{{ foo }} {# out: bar #}
{% do set('foo', 'foo') %}
{{ foo }} {# out: foo #}
```

Comment: Cool thanks ! That's exactly what I needed ! Thanks again :) Do you also know if this is also possible with filters?

Comment: With a filter you'd just return a value which could overwrite the value if you did `{% set foo = foo|my_filter %}`. No need there to send the context

Comment: I mostly use this snippet above to alter an array value though. Signature becomes `setArrayValue(&$context, $array_name, $index, $value)` then