# Twig set variable name using a variable

Tags: twig

Is it possible to iterate through an array and set twig variables using the array keys as the variable name and the values as the values? For example my array:

```
[
  "key1": "value",
  "key2": "value2,
]
```

In twig:

```
{% for key,value in array %}
  {% set {{ key }} = value %}
{% endfor %}
```

Expected result would be:

```
key1 = value
key2 = value2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig variables as references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247917/twig-variables-as-references)

Comment: This does not look like it accomplishes what I'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How does it not? See [here](https://www.darkbee.be/stack/change_context.php) for a working demo

Comment: Thanks for sending the demo over. That looks like it works.